# Why spring batch does not have jobinstance context to share data between different jobexecutions of same jobinstanceid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job where we are doing the following tasks .

```
<job>

         <tasklet1>send msg to external sys1 </task1>

        <!--After sending message to sys1 stop the job -->

        <!--listener to read response from sys1 and restart job from tasklet2  using jobexecutiondecider -->

        <tasklet2>Process response from sys1</tasklet>

        <tasklet3>send msg to external sys2</task1>

        <!--After sending message to sys2 stop the job -->

        <!--listener to read response from sys2 and restart job from tasklet4  using jobexecutiondecider -->

        <tasklet4>Process response from sys2</tasklet>

</job>
```

Spring batch table will have three job executions for the same job instance id since we are restarting same job instance id multiple times as shown below.

- Jobexe1.1
- Jobexe1.2
- Jobexe1.3

Now I am facing a problem where a value that was set into jobexecution context of Jobexe1.1 is not there in the context of Jobexe1.2.

**Question:**
1 If I store something in jobexecution context of Jobexe1.1 ,
would that be available to jobexecution context of Jobexe1.2 ?

**Question2:** If above is not the case then how do we share data between different job executions of job instance id 1?

**Question3:** Why spring batch does not have something like jobinstance execution context so that we can easily share data between different job executions of one job instance id ?

**Note-** I am aware of stepexecutioncontext for sharing data within a step and jobexecutioncontext for sharing data between steps for a jobexecution .

Comment: how do you set the value into the jobExecutionContext?

Comment: What you put in the job execution **will** be available on the next execution, provided that the step during which this change is made is allowed to complete (successfully or not). So you're probably doing something wrong somewhere, but you'd need to give more details.

Comment: @MichaelPralow I am using  chunk context and from there getting job ec=xecutiona nd setting it as shown below chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getJobExecution() .getExecutionContext().put("value", "foo");

Comment: @Artefacto   What more information you would like to know from me ?

Comment: @DevG Put a breakpoint at `JobRepository::updateExecutionContext`, then figure out if the method is not being called at all or if the transaction where the table is updated is being rolled back.